# hadoop / hbase virus

Tags: hbase, virus-scanning

We have a Java EE based web application that will allow users to upload various types of files (pdf, MS Word etc.).  We are looking at storing these files in HBase but there are concerns over potential threats from a file that is uploaded that may contain a virus or other malware.

What approaches might be taken to virus scan the files uploaded?

Comment: You could always have a virus scanner on your server which automatically scans all new files or, if possible, only the files in a certain directory, e.g. your upload directory.

Comment: Thanks.  Does the way Hbase / Hadoop distributes data have any impact?  Would the file uploaded by the user be byte-for-byte the same on HDFS?

Comment: I hope the file integrity does not change, otherwise that would be a huge drawback ... But about the distribution: Obviously the check would need to be done immediately after receiving the file, before putting it into the database (of any kind).